# Determine the expected value and variance of the random variable (density function)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, density-function

Task from an [old exam](https://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~koessler/MathematikInformatiker/KlausurB.pdf) (but in German):

> Given is $Y \sim f $ with density $f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
> \frac{1}{2}\cos(x) \text{ }\text{ }\text{ if } x \in
> \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]\\  0 \text{ }\text{ }\text{
> }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{
> }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{
> }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{
> }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ else } \end{matrix}\right.$
>
> Determine the expected value $E(X)$ and the variance $Var(X_i).$

I'm preparing for an exam. I know how to determine $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$ if we got a matrix given but no idea about this task with density : /

But I think you need to integrate that one function inside this density which has intervals, so:

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}\cos(x)\text{ } dx} = \left [\frac{1}{2} \sin(x) +c \right ]_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} = \frac{1}{2} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+c - \left(\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+c\right) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1$$

How do you get the expected value and variance from it? :s

Comment: Use 
$$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{xf_{X}(x)dx}$$ where $f_X$ is the density function of $X$.

Furthermore,
$$E(X^2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x^2f_{X}(x)dx}$$

Comment: Do you know definitions of $\operatorname{E}(X)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X)$?

Comment: The expectation is $E(X)=0$

Comment: For the variance, see here : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral(x%3D-pi%2F2,pi%2F2,x%5E2cos(x)%2F2)

Comment: @Peter Thank you for the link, I will try to calculate it per hand first and compare it after. Maybe you can check my calculation below (the comment in Mr. Chip's answer)? If my approach is correct

Comment: @cnmesr Yes, your approach is correct, the limits for the below integral are $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ here (because outside these limits the density-function is $0$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: By the definitions, [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) is given by $$\text{E}(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x) \, dx$$ and [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) is given by $$\text{Var}(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 f(x) \, dx - \text{E}(X)^2.$$
So you're going to need to integrate $\frac{1}{2} x \cos x$ and $\frac{1}{2} x^2 \cos x$ on the prescribed interval; in both cases you can use symmetry to make your task easier, since the former function is odd and the latter is even.

Comment: For the expected value:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x \cdot \frac{1}{2}\cos(x) dx = \left[\frac{x \cdot \sin(x)+\cos(x)}{2}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$ But how can you know the result if you put those intervals in? $sin$ and $cos$ will oscillate and you cannot know the result, or can you?

Comment: @cnmesr Notice $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{-\pi/2} 0\,dx+\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(x)\,dx}{2}+\int_{\pi/2}^\infty 0\,dx$$ The terms whose integrantes are $0$ will evaluate to $0$.

Comment: The point is that $f$ is not exactly $(x/2) \cos x$. It's zero except on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. So integrating it $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is the same as integrating it $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.